# was mir erleichtert die Lernbereitschaft jeder weiteren Programmiersprache zu erlernen

Tags: word-usage

Kann man erlernen mit Lernbereitschaft verwenden oder gibts eines besseres Synonym?

> Bei der langjährigen Anwendung von Java eignete ich mir fortgeschrittene Programmierkenntnisse an, was mir erleichtert die Lernbereitschaft jeder weiteren Programmiersprache zu erlernen. Des Weiteren verfüge ich über eine gute Android-, PHP-, C-, HTML-, CSS-, SQL-, JavaScript-Kenntnisse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lernen und Lernbereitschaft sind keine Synonyme.

In Deinem Text macht Lernbereitschaft so keinen Sinn, da Lernbereitschaft lediglich den *Willen zu lernen* beschreibt, nicht irgendeine Art der Befähigung, Begabung oder vorhandene Grundlagen.

Du möchtest aber darauf hinweisen, dass Du auf vorhandenen Kenntnissen aufbauend leichter neue Sprachen lernen kannst. Das steht aber schon ohne "Lernbereitschaft" so im Text:

> ... was [es] mir erleichtert, jede weitere Programmiersprache zu erlernen.

Falls Du dagegen "Lernbereitschaft" mit "Grundlagen" oder "Prinzipien" o.ä. verwechselt haben solltest, würde Dein Satz z.B. lauten:

> ... was mir erleichtert, die Grundlagen jeder weiteren Programmiersprache zu erlernen.

Comment: Persönliche Anmerkung: Manche Programmiersprachen haben völlig andere Paradigmen, vielleicht ist der Anspruch, *jede weitere* Programmiersprache leicht zu lernen, etwas zu hoch gegriffen. Ich habe schon einige Java-Profis heftig mit z.B. Haskell kämpfen sehen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde den Teil mit der Lernbereitschaft ganz weglassen, also

> was mir erleichtert, jede weitere Programmiersprache zu erlernen

**Erklärung:** In Deiner Frage klingt der Satz, als ob Du die *Lernbereitschaft* erlernst, das macht wenig Sinn.
Ich denke, Du willst ausdrücken, dass Du die *Programmiersprache* erlernst.